# Stored procedure for deleting a record does not seem to work

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I'm experiencing an issue with an access form. I use access 2013 forms as frontend, and sql server 2014 as backend. The form has a button that should delete a record, through use of a stored procedure. Though, when I select the record that should be deleted, and when I press the button, it seems to have worked. The stored procedure has to delete 1 record in 2 different tables, which are linked together with 'articlenr'.

I can debug through the entire process (except for the stored procedure). I'm guessing there's something wrong with my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spArticleDelete]
(
    @articlenr int
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Article
    WHERE articlenr = @articlenr
    ) <> 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Articleprice WHERE articlenr = @articlenr
        DELETE FROM Article WHERE articlenr = @articlenr
    END

    If @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            Raiserror('The article has been deleted!', 16, 1)
        END
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK
        Raiserror('The article has not been deleted!', 16,1)
```

Hope you guys can help me out here..

Comment: Why are you using RAISERROR to return messages? I would remove the entire IF condition and just delete the rows. Not much point in looking to see if they exist and then deleting them. Just delete them, if they don't exist it won't delete anything.

Comment: What are the options on your tables/links? Depending on the configuration, the database will not allow you to delete a record from one table that is linked to a record in another table.

Comment: Alright, though changing that does not make the sp do what it's supposed to do :/

Well, that's why I'm deleting both tables, since they're the only ones that are linked to each other, there are no other links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change your code to somethis like this:

```
  begin try
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DELETE FROM x2 where i1 = 5
            DELETE FROM x2 where i1 = 6

    commit
    Raiserror('The article has been deleted!', 16, 1)

  end try

   begin catch
       if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       begin
                  ROLLBACK
       end
       Raiserror('The article has not been deleted!', 16,1)

   end catch
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the try/catch method, what exactly does it do?

Comment: Try catch was introduced in SQL Server 2005. Its a lot cleaner then using @@error (which needs to be checked after every statement). Begin try tells SQL Server if any  error occurs immediately jump to the begin catch block and execute whatever code is there.

Comment: This is much cleaner but I would not use RAISERROR to return a message. If you want to return a message use a select statement or an output variable.

Comment: Sean is right - its not a good idea to use raiserror. Raiserror 16 is really misleading because it indicates a severity level of 16 which if a row is deleted successfully is probably not a sever error.